# Quaternion and the closest point on the sphere

Tags: opengl, geometry, quaternions, closest

I usung quaternion to rotate the sphere in 3d space.

Sphere is placed at p = (0, 0, 0)

The question is: how i can find the point and/or face closest to camera.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. A sphere has the nice property, that it is formed by the set of all points which distance from the center has a certain value (the radius).

In OpenGL we assume that the observer is located at the origin. Objects are placed in their individual coordinate space by means of a linear transformation (modelview). So all we must do is find the position of the observer in the local coordinate system of the sphere and normalize the vector toward the local space observer position toward unit length.

The transformation is the full modelview matrix *MV*. Your quaternion *q* can be mapped to a matrix *R*. Assuming that *q*, i.e. *R* define the rotation of the sphere within its own local frame, the total transformation toward view space becomes

```
p_view = MV · R · p_local
```

where *p* is the set of the sphere's points.

Hence the observer local to the sphere's frame reference is located at

```
o_local = inv(MV · R) · (0,0,0,1)
```

Last you've to rescale the local frame location vector toward the observer to the sphere's radius

```
o_direction_on_sphere = radious · o_local / len(o_local)
```